# Same package but a different signature

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, sha1, android-keystore

I have integrated Google Sign-In into my Android application which is already on Google Play. Application had Firebase Email Authentication and I wanted to allow user to sign in with Google account. I have tested it, install app in debug mode and it worked perfectly. After that I generated signed APK, uploaded as a new release, uninstalled app and downloaded from Google Play to check if it's working. And it didn't.

I got message **Google SignIn Fails** with code **10** . I've done some research, read some topics and it all indicates that my SHA1 is not set up properly. I'll get to my SHA1 later.

I uninstalled my app again, run it from Android Studio again and got message
[image: app installation failed]

Of course, after accepting it Google SingIn worked again. And now I have few questions:

1. At Firebase Settings, my SHA certificate is the same one that I get in **Task --> android --> signinReport** (SHA-1 : **d5:1b**:xx:xx:xx:xx:...:xx), but at **GooglePlay --> App singing** I have another (SHA-1 **05:FE**:xx:xx:...:xx). Should they be the same?
2. What should I do? Of course, I don't want to "damage" my connection with Firebase. I'd rather leave it without Google SingIn than lose my users.
3. I had an keystore_file and for some reason (probably Android Studio reinstall, forgot password or whatever) I generated a new one. Now I have two keystore files, the old and new one.
   Would my problems be solved if I tried to go back to the old one?
   I'll guess the password somehow :)

Any help would be precious, so thanks in advance.

Edit: If I try to add SHA1 from App Signing (SHA-1 **05:FE**:xx:xx:...:xx) to Firebase -->  "An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project."

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your questions

1. No
2. Relates to 1
3. You'll only have "problems" if this is the key you use for release

Normally during app development you have 2 keys.

- The first one for development/Debug (this can be the default used be android studio, and probably the one you see under signing report)
- The second is for release builds (the one you use to sign the artifacts and publish to the play store)

The first and the second key, can be the same, but it is recommended that they are not the same.

Since you enabled Play Signing, the final release version that users install your app from play store, has the signing you see at the Console Panel, so, in firebase you should register both keys, the one Google Play signs with and the debug key, so you can test you app locally

Comment: I've tried to add sha1 from GooglePlay Console and got some "error message". I thought I shouldn't have done it. "Another project" :-o

Comment: You definitely can have more than one Firebase Project, that is an ok approach too

Comment: Just be aware that you debug build must have a different application package name

Comment: No, actually I've tried to register both keys... but I wasn't be allowed

Comment: For example, on your firebase project.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIvKt.png you can see your apps at the top...

Comment: When you click one of them... https://i.stack.imgur.com/B36Bt.png you can add the SHA-1 keys of a package

Comment: Can you check how many apps do you have... and also, if the key you are tring to add is in another package

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xde8nr

just one app, and still the same message